# The volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y=5x$ and $y=x^2$ about$ x=5$.

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

How do I solve this? I tried to give the integral from $0$ to $25\pi((5x)^2-(x^2)^2)$ but it is wrong and I don't understand why I also need it with cylindrical shells.

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question if you want it to be taken seriously. It would also help if you provided the answer you got. A couple of comments on your integral: 1) there are *two* points of intersection of these two curves, 2) Did you intend the last "^2" to be outside the last parenthesis?

Comment: You don't have to use shells, but it is generally the easier way to go when rotating around a vertical line.  If you want to use disks/washers you will need to find expressions of x in terms of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the integral $$\pi\int^{25}_0\left[\left(5-\frac{y}{5}\right)^2-\left(5-\sqrt{y}\right)^2\right]dy$$
[image: graph]

Comment: thank you this was very helpful i was missing th 5- in my integral and im assuming we add this due to the point of intersection 5,25